# How to decide the resistance required to power a LED using triboelectric nano-generators?

Tags: electrostatics, electronics, nanoscience

I tried to power LEDs using triboelectric nanogenerators, https://youtu.be/OAmpvhRE4Ws, but found that I was unable to light even a single LED. Do it requires to connect resistors in series with LEDs to power it? If yes, then how to decide the resistance?

Comment: An LED will light if the right amount of _current_ is flowing through it. For small "indicator" LEDs that could be as little as 5mA or as much as 30mA. In order to make the current flow, the circuit will have to provide a minimum voltage that depends on the color of the LED. Around 1.8V for red LEDs to somewhere in the neighborhood of 4V for blue. It is very easy to drive too much current through an LED, which will destroy it, if you use a constant voltage power supply. A series resistor between an LED and a constant voltage supply is an easy/cheap way to limit the current.

Comment: Q: How much current can your "nano generator" supply? and at what voltage?